# Implement filter for Enum to check value before insert

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I want to store available user roles into Enum:

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT;

  public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
  }

}
```

Entity value:

```
@Column(length = 25)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;
```

I create new user using the code:

```
Users user = new Users();
user.setRole(Role.valueOf("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

Is there someway to make a check is ROLE_ADMIN a valid Enum value because I can break the code it's not a valid value.

Comment: `valueOf` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the String does not match a value value, so you can catch that.  This is how the check is usually done.

Comment: @racraman Why not make an Answer of your Comment?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. If you are creating the a new instance of `Users`, you can use `setRole(Role.ROLE_ADMIN)` directly. If really, the rol value "comes" from a front application (or other source) in a "string way", then maybe you can include that code here to help you in a better way.

Comment: yes in my case the value comes from Angular as String, so I need to implement some king of check of the received value.

Comment: @PeterPenzov what do you think about my answer?

Comment: It's a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an specific method in your enum to know if the provided string matches or not with an specific one. Something like:

```
public static Optional<Role> getFromString(String valueToCheck) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(valueToCheck)
            .flatMap(toCheck -> Arrays.stream(Role.values())
                       .filter(r -> toCheck.equals(r.name()))
                       .findFirst());
}
```

Or use another approaches of the above one:

1. Change `Optional<Role>` by `Role` and use `.orElse(null)`.
2. Change `Optional<Role>` by `Role` and use `.orElseThrow(...)` to throw an exception.